# My in app purchases stopped working after changing app name?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, in-app-purchase

I changed my app name in xcode and also in itunes connect. I then went and tried to test my in app purchases but they don't work. Can someone please help me fix this? I don't what to do to get this to be resolved.

Comment: okay so I changed the name back to the original and the in app purchases work. Could I just change the display name and the name in itunes connect instead of changing the bundle identifier and everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to manually set the `Bundle Identifier` in your app info, then you can change the `Product Name` separately.

*Note: You need to make sure the bundle ID is the original ID you setup in iTunes Connect*

[image]

Comment: I set the bundle identifier to what it was originally. And then I changed the bundle display name to the new app name. Is that okay?

Comment: If by `Bundle Display Name` you mean `Product Name` then It should be fine - have you tested it, is it working?

Comment: The bundle display name changes the name below the app icon. Is that the same as product name?